# SSL WordPress on AWS - Domain does not resolve ... fix DNS entries

Tags: wordpress, ssl, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, bitnami

Just trying to set up SSL https for my site, using the Bitnami Tool bncert-tool. It shall automate the SSL setup by naming the domain. Unfortunately, I get the message

> Warning: The domain 'mypage' does not resolve, please fix its DNS entries or remove it.
>   Press [Enter] to continue:

Thing is, I can get to the page via domain name and the IP.  So no Problem on that side.

I have no clue! I have set up an elastic IP in EC2 and connected the domain in Route53 by adding the dataset. Has some faced the problem before and cases.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, did both non-www and www domains resolve properly? Are they configured using the instance's IP? You can use this online tool to verify everything https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: Hey, thank you. 
seems to me it was my n00b problem. Within Route 53 and setting up the domain, only the non-www domain was set up. Directing the url to the www in addition solved the problem. Cp the www url did not resolve.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the warning message, 'mypage' is not a domain. Actually have to enter in the full domain path such as

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
or
google.com

Good luck.